# window and tab close detection

Tags: javascript

there are many articles for window and tab close detection, however, since the newest browser published, those codes since not working anymore. [webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event](http://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/) is an article for webkit browsers. It use onPageHiden() to detect the leave page event, however, it seems no longer work in chrome. Also, if I just close the browser, It won't do anything also.

How I can trigger an event when I not only close the tab but also close the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can trigger an event when I not only close the tab but also close the browser?

You can't. You can detect when a page gets closed if the browser allows you; you can't tell *why* it was closed.